How to set up a UIHostingController with transparent background used as a child VC to pass through tap events to UIViews underneath?
I am trying to use SwiftUI and UIHostingController to add an overlay view to my existing UIKit view. In my case, it's presenting a stack of small semi-opaque notification bubbles over a complex video view.
I have read and understand previous questions related to creating a UIHostingController with a transparent background:
struct MostlyTransparentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Capsule()
                .background(.blue)
                .frame(height: 30, width: 100)
                .onTapGesture { print("Button tapped!") }
        }
        .background(.clear)
    }
}

let vc = UIHostingController(rootView: MostlyTransparentView())
vc.view.backgroundColor = .clear
vc.view.isOpaque = false

Now, if I were to add this view controller as a child view controller of another VC and insert its view into the view heirarchy of the parent, such that its view overlays some other UIViews such as buttons that appear underneath the Spacer:
// Assume this exists, and it contains views that want to receive tap gestures but
// would be underneath the transparent parts of vc.view.
let someOtherVC: UIViewController

someOtherVC.addChild(vc)
someOtherVC.someSubView.addSubview(vc.view)
vc.didMove(toParent: someOtherVC)

... is there any way to set up the UIHostingController and its root view such that taps on those views underneath the transparent areas are passed through to the underlying UIViews? Or should I give up and implement using UIKit?

I cannot add .allowHitTesting(false) to the VStack because I want the Capsule to receive tap gestures.

I cannot set .isUserInteractionEnabled = false on vc.view for the same reason.

I tried adding .allowHitTesting(false) to the Spacer; that did not work.

As far as I know, I cannot modify the hitTest(_:with:) method of vc.view to ignore taps on the root view, nor insert a UIView subclass of my own that modifies its hit testing thusly.



In SwiftUI I often use Color.white.opacity(0.001) instead of .clear to let the tap pass through.
You could try this vc.view.backgroundColor = Color.white.opacity(0.001) with the UIKit.

@workingdogsupportUkraine can you elaborate?  How does the style applied to the background determine pass through of tap?

I was just testing code where Color.clear
does not responds to tap, but Color.white.opacity(0.001) does.

Strange, but worth knowing!

@workingdogsupportUkraine Please clarify: did you mean to set a different .background(Color.white.opacity(0.001) on the SwiftUI view, or set a vc.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.001)?

Chris, sorry, I’ll withdraw my comments as I can see they are creating confusion. I was just testing some code that showed the difference
between taps on .clear and low .opacity colors and thought this could be an avenue to explore.
I’ve lost the ability to understand UIKit, UIViewController etc… and mixing those with SwiftUI,
so don’t attach any significance to my comments.
